# Voltages from battery to motor

Tags: voltage

I’m bad at electronics/new, If my battery is 19V going to a 12V motor how do I lower the voltage from the battery to the motor? Would a resistor do the trick? Thanks for any responses in advance.

Comment: Use a voltage regulator. Even better, use a motor driver.

Comment: What is the current?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about controlling the speed of the motor, a simple 12V regulator would do the trick. What kind you get will vary depending on how much current you're expecting to draw, but they're mostly cheap and readily available.

However, if you do want to control the motor's speed or direction, you'll need to look into a motor controller. [Here](https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/pwm-motor-controllers.html)'s a good place to start looking for something like that.